How to replace Finder and make SpaceDrive as the default file explorer on Mac
I have started using Spacedrive on Mac. But the default Finder is still in use. I want to replace Finder and use SpaceDrive as the default Explorer, such that all default actions such as save file, download file, Spacedrive is used, instead of Finder.
How can I do that?

To bring up a file open/save dialog, Applications just ask the OS to create one, which then returns the opened file (in the case of 'Open'), or reports success (in the case of "Save").
SpaceDrive would have to offer some method of 'intercepting' file open and save dialogs (involving a fair amount of code). I don't know how difficult, or even possible that would be. (There are some apps that modify the dialogs, I think, like Default Folder X.)
This isn't something you'll be able to do for yourself, (e.g. with a couple of plist options).
As SpaceDrive is a new app, still in Alpha, you may want to ask that they include this feature.
